Show that the kernel $|x -y|^{-1}$ on $\mathbb{R}^3 \times \mathbb{R}^3$ is Hilbert Schmidt with respect to a weighted $L^2$ space
Let $\langle x \rangle := (1 + |x|^2)^{1/2}$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$. For $s > 1$, consider the weighted convolution operator
\begin{equation*}
T_s \varphi = \langle x \rangle^{-s} \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \frac{ \langle y \rangle^{-s} \varphi(y)}{|x-y|} dy, \qquad \varphi \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^3).
\end{equation*}
I would like to show that the kernel $\langle x \rangle^{-s} \langle y \rangle^{-s}|x-y|^{-1}$ is Hilbert-Schmidt on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$. That is, I want to show
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\langle x \rangle^{-2s} \langle y \rangle^{-2s}|x-y|^{-2}dx dy < \infty. 
\end{equation*}
This finiteness is claimed, for instance, in Lemma 2.1 of Jensen and Kato's classical work (1979) on the expansion of the resolvent of the Schrödinger operator at low frequency. But a proof is not given. More generally, I would like to know for which $s$ the kernel $\langle x \rangle^{-s} \langle y \rangle^{-s}|x-y|^{-n + 2}$ is Hilbert-Schmidt on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$.
I know of the standard proof of $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$-boundedness of $\langle x \rangle^{-s_1} \langle y \rangle^{-s_2}|x-y|^{-1}$, $s_1, \, s_2 > 1/2$, $s_1 + s_2 > 2$, which passes to the Fourier transform side and uses boundedness properties of the Fourier transform. However, I would like to know if when $s_1 = s_2 = s$, this may be avoided and the Hilbert-Schmidt norm may be estimated directly. My attempt so far is naive:
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\langle x \rangle^{-2s} \langle y \rangle^{-2s}|x-y|^{-2}dx dy = 
\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \langle x \rangle^{-2s} \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \langle x -y \rangle^{-2s}|y|^{-2} dy dx.
\end{equation*}
The goal now is of course to contend with the fact that $\langle x -y \rangle^{-2s}$ does not decay on the diagonal. For this, I wonder if there is a clever way of splitting up the domain of integration, and is where I am stuck.

I mean, near $0$ it is integrable (cause $\frac{1}{|x-y|^2}$ is), and outside the vicinity of $0$ replace $$ with $|x|$ and just take the integral in spherical coordinates? Since $4s + 2-5 > 1$ it will also be integrable.

But $|x-y|^{-n+2}$ doesn't work, if you need it to be integrable near $0$, you want $2(-n+2)>-n$, which is equivalent to $4 > n$, so $n = 1, 2, 3$ are the only cases.

This follows from the asymptotics of $J(x)=\int_{\mathbb R^n}|x-y|^{-\gamma} (1+|y|)^{-\beta}dy$ assuming $\gamma<n, \gamma+\beta >n$. In the worst case $\beta<n$, $J$ decays like $|x|^{n-(\alpha+\beta)}$. One needs integration in spheircal coordinates...and some time.

Where can I find the standard proof you mention above for $s_1, s_2 > 1/2$ and $s_1+s_2>2$?

@GiorgioMetafune Thank you for your hint about $J(x)$. I will try to use it. For the proof I mention, see Chapter 6, Lemma 18.4 of Komech-Kopylova, Dispersion Decay and Scattering Theory (John Wiley & Sons 2012).

By the way, I find that $T$ is Hilbert Schmidt if $s_1, s_2>1/2$ and $s_1+s_2>2$. Is this coherent with your thoughts? I can give the details if you wish.

@GiorgioMetafune Indeed, Jensen-Kato state that the kernel is Hilbert-Schmidt even in this more general case. I just wasn't so sure. I still need to think more about your $J(x)$ hint. I guess the trick must be to split up the integral into integral over ${|y| \le c|x|}$ and ${|y| > c|x|}$ for appropriately chosen $c$.

Even though @FedorPetrov altready answered, maybe it is interesting to see a proof in the general case, based on the asymptotics of
$$J(x)= \int_{\mathbb R^n} \frac{dy}{|x-y|^\gamma (1+|y|)^\beta}
$$
if $\gamma<n$ and $\gamma+\beta >n$. It decays at infinity like $|x|^{n-\gamma-\beta}$ when $\beta<n$, $|x|^{-\gamma}$ when $\beta>n$ and $|x|^{-\gamma}\log |x|$ when $\beta=n$.
Fix $x$ and split the integral over the three sets
\begin{align*}
&E_1=\{|y-x| \leq \frac 12 |x|\},\quad  \ E_2=\{|y-x| \geq \frac 12 |x|, \quad |y| \geq 2|x|\} \\ & E_3=\{|y-x| \geq \frac 12 |x|, \quad |y| \leq 2|x|\}
\end{align*}
so that $J=J_1+J_2+J_3$.
Then $|y| \geq \frac 12 |x|$ on $E_1$ and this gives
$$
J_1(x) \leq C|x|^{-\beta} \int_{2|z| \leq |x|} \frac{dz}{|z|^\gamma} \leq C|x|^{n-\gamma-\beta}.$$
For $J_2$ we use only $|y| \geq 2|x|$ which implies $|y-x| \geq |y|/2$ to get
$$J_2(x) \leq C\int_{|y| \geq 2|x|} \frac{dy}{|y|^{\gamma+\beta}}\leq C|x|^{n-\gamma-\beta}.
$$
Finally
$$
J_3(x) \leq C|x|^{-\gamma}\int_{|y| \leq 2|x|} \frac{dy}{(1+|y|)^\beta}
$$
and this gives the same estimate when $\beta<n$, $|x|^{-\gamma} \log |x|$ when $\beta=n$ and $|x|^{-\gamma}$ when $\beta>n$.
These estimates are optimal up to constants. For lower bounds $|y| \leq \frac 32 |x|$ gives
$$
J(x) \geq \int_{B(x, \frac 12 |x|)}\frac{dy}{|x-y|^\gamma (1+|y|)^\beta} \geq C|x|^{-\beta} \int_{B(x, \frac 12 |x|)}\frac{dy}{|x-y|^{\gamma}}=C|x|^{n-\gamma-\beta}
$$
and $|x-y| \leq 3|y|$
$$
J(x) \geq \int_{|y| \leq 2|x|}\frac{dy}{|x-y|^\gamma (1+|y|)^\beta} \geq C|x|^{-\gamma} \int_{|y| \leq 2|x|} \frac{dy}{(1+|y|)^\beta}.
$$

The first case works also if $(1+|y|)^\beta$ is replaced by $|y|^\beta$ for $\beta<n$

Interestingly, $J(x)$ can be expressed in terms of Gauss's hypergeometric function $_2F_1$. This is perhaps an older result, but you can find it in Corollary 1 in my paper https://doi.org/10.1007/s00365-016-9336-4, see also entry no. 4 in Table 1 in my survey https://doi.org/10.1515/9783110571622-007.

@MateuszKwaśnicki Thank you, I did not know...looks complicate

Consider a more general question: when $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\langle x \rangle^{-s} \langle y \rangle^{-t}|x-y|^{-p}dxdy<\infty\tag{1}$$
for non-negative $s,t,p$. I claim that the necessary and sufficient conditions are $$s+p>n, t+p>n, s+p+t>2n, p<n.$$

If $p\geqslant n$, than for every $x$ the integral over $y$ within distance  1 from $x$ does diverge, so the whole integral diverges. Let further $p<n$.

The integral over $\{(x,y):\min(|x|,|y|)<1\}$ is dominated by the integral over $\Omega:=\{(x,y):\min(|x|,|y|)\geqslant 1\}$. Indeed, choose a fixed vector $v$ of length 5 and for $|x|<1,|y|<10$ consider the point $(x+3v,y+3v)\in \Omega$ with the comparable value of the integrand as at $(x,y)$, and for $|x|<1,|y|>10$ take the point $(x+v,y+v)\in \Omega$. Thus further we integrate over $\Omega$ and may write $|x|$ instead of $\langle x\rangle$.

The useful trick in such questions is to replace the integral to the series over dyadic regions. Namely, partition $\Omega$ onto the products of annuli $R_{m,k}:=\{x:2^{m}\leqslant |x|<2^{m+1},2^{k}\leqslant |y|<2^{k+1}\}$, over non-negative integers $m,k$. On each $R_{m,k}$ with $|m-k|\geqslant 2$ the integrand is about a constant $2^{-ms-kt-\max(m,k)p}$. When $|m-k|\leqslant 1$, it is (up to a constant factor) a lower bound for the integrand, but sometimes $|x-y|$ is too small. But since $\int_{|x|<1}|x|^{-p}dx$ converges (recall that $p<n$), we have by scaling $\int_{|x|<R}|x|^{-p}dx\asymp\int_{R/2<|x|<R}|x|^{-p}dx$ uniformly for all $R>0$. Therefore, if $|m-k|\leqslant 1$, after the integration over $R_{m,k}$ the pairs $(x,y)$ with $|x-y|<2^k/100$ do not contribute more than other pairs, and we may still think that the integrand is approximately constant.

So, we reduced the question to the convergence of the double series $$\sum_{m,k} 2^{(m+k)n-ms-kt-\max(m,k)p}.$$
If, say, $m\geqslant k$, for fixed $k$ the summation over $m\geqslant k$ gives infinity if $n-s-p\geqslant 0$ and gives $\asymp 2^{(k+k)n-ks-kt-kp}$ otherwise. Therefore, the necessary conditions of the convergence are $n-s-p<0$ and $2n-t-s-p<0$, and they are also sufficient for the convergence of the sum over pairs with $m\geqslant k$. The case $m<k$ is analogous, we get an extra  condition $n-t-p<0$.


